# How to call common JavaScript function to all the files without adding it in every JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have a log.js file(it contains log function along with some properties) for debugging purpose.
I have two other js file which are the controlling various behavior of the web application.
Now I need to  include the log function considering not to repeat the debug function in both the js file and just calling the file name.
How do I do it?
The idea is to make my code clean and separate them in other files to limit the size of a single js file.

Comment: Just add them to the `<head>` tag in order that they need to load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include all .js-files in the html page. Include log.js first.
Call the functions all you want.

Comment: I did it. But in console I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: log is not defined "

Comment: Post your HTML this should be fine

Comment: Then you have to show us some more code on how you include the files and how you declare and use the functions.

Comment: Yep did the trick. I was loading another page. My mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

All functions in all files are included in the source and are "written on the page", any functions can be accessed from anywhere within the HTML as they all become essentially one document. Make sure you do not have duplicate functions as this could cause an issue